# How to handle external links in WebView after share button is clicked?

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I have a screen which loads a webview, now for handling opening of external apps and other links, I've used url.startsWith() and url.contains(). These work fine for the webview. There is a home button that also uses the same functionality of the webview for handling external links.

## My problem

There is also a share button on the top toolbar, the problem is when that button is clicked, the links aren't handled  anymore by the above methods even though I have used them in the share button.

Here is the code for handling links inside the webview which works for onCreate and homeIcon methods but not for shareText():

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {


    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        myWebView.loadUrl("https://google.com");

        Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webSettings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
        webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
        webSettings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");


        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {


            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                if (url != null && (url.startsWith("whatsapp://") || url.startsWith("tel") || url.startsWith("market"))) {
                    view.getContext().startActivity(
                            new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
                    return true;
                } else {

                    assert url != null;
                    if (url.startsWith("intent://") && url.contains("scheme=http")) {
                        url = Uri.decode(url);
                        String bkpUrl = null;
                        Pattern regexBkp = Pattern.compile("intent://(.*?)#");
                        Matcher regexMatcherBkp = regexBkp.matcher(url);
                        if (regexMatcherBkp.find()) {
                            bkpUrl = regexMatcherBkp.group(1);
                            Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://" + bkpUrl));
                            startActivity(myIntent);
                            return true;
                        } else {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
                }

            }
        });

    }



    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    public void shareText(View view) {
        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        myWebView.loadUrl("https://google.com");

        Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webSettings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
        webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
        webSettings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");

        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {


            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                if (url != null && (url.startsWith("whatsapp://") || url.startsWith("tel") || url.startsWith("market"))) {
                    view.getContext().startActivity(
                            new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
                    return true;
                } else {

                    assert url != null;
                    if (url.startsWith("intent://") && url.contains("scheme=http")) {
                        url = Uri.decode(url);
                        String bkpUrl = null;
                        Pattern regexBkp = Pattern.compile("intent://(.*?)#");
                        Matcher regexMatcherBkp = regexBkp.matcher(url);
                        if (regexMatcherBkp.find()) {
                            bkpUrl = regexMatcherBkp.group(1);
                            Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://" + bkpUrl));
                            startActivity(myIntent);
                            return true;
                        } else {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
                }

            }
        });


        Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        String shareBodyText = "Check out this awesome store at https://showroom.dotpe.in/stylenstyle882. Or download the app now.";
        intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject/Title");
        intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBodyText);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Sharing Option"));




    }


    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    public void homeIcon(View view){


        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        myWebView.loadUrl("https://google.com");

        Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webSettings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
        webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
        webSettings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");

        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {


            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                if (url != null && (url.startsWith("whatsapp://") || url.startsWith("tel") || url.startsWith("market"))) {
                    view.getContext().startActivity(
                            new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
                    return true;
                } else {

                    assert url != null;
                    if (url.startsWith("intent://") && url.contains("scheme=http")) {
                        url = Uri.decode(url);
                        String bkpUrl = null;
                        Pattern regexBkp = Pattern.compile("intent://(.*?)#");
                        Matcher regexMatcherBkp = regexBkp.matcher(url);
                        if (regexMatcherBkp.find()) {
                            bkpUrl = regexMatcherBkp.group(1);
                            Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://" + bkpUrl));
                            startActivity(myIntent);
                            return true;
                        } else {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
                }

            }
        });


    }
```

How should I handle this? Or the buttons in the toolbar can't handle this?

Comment: What happen if you don't substitute the URL?

Comment: You mean if I don't handle the opening of external links? It just shows ERR_UNKNOWN_URI_SCHEME for each link clicked

Comment: Looking at `Chrome`, this is what it sends: `intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Uri.parse("https://stackoverflow.com"));`

Comment: Yes I handled intent, see the code above. The thing is everything I've tried is working in home button and the webview screen but as soon as I press the button on the top toolbar, the webview refreshes and then no links are handled

Comment: you may have to check what js script function is being run when you click on the share button, then try to override that script fun inside Android code

Answer (score 0):

I think when you click on your toolbar then WebView just opens up the link and the very first time the shouldOverrideUrlLoading will not be called so you need to call the logic of this URL filtering while loading the URL on Webview on click of the toolbar button.

Comment: The logic is being called on the first screen in the WebView and when I call the WebView on click of the home button by the very same method

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
String shareBodyText = "Check out this awesome store at https://showroom.dotpe.in/stylenstyle882. Or download the app now.";
intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject/Title");
intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBodyText);
// Here are 1 added lines to handle URLs.
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("http://" + bkpUrl));
// Here are 2 added lines to share a file.
// intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://" + filePath));
// intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("content://" + getPackageName() + ".file" + filePath), "text/plain");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Sharing Option"));
```